# Concurrent read and writers through cloned data structures?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, locking, distributed, lock-free

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262232/concurrent-data-structure-design) question but it didn't  really help.

**First and most important thing: time performances are the focus in the application that I'm developing**

We have a client/server model (even distributed or cloud if we wish) and a data structure `D` hosted on the server. Each client request consists in:

1. Read something from `D`
2. *Eventually* write something on `D`
3. *Eventually* delete something on `D`

We can say that in this application the relation between the number of received operations can be described as `delete<<write<<read`. In addition:

1. Read ops cannot absolutely wait: they **must** be processed immediately
2. Write and delete can wait some time, but sooner is better.

From the description above, any lock-mechanism is not acceptable: this would imply that read operations could wait, which is **not** acceptable (sorry if I stress it so much, but it's really a crucial point).

Consistency is not necessary: if a write/delete operation has been performed and then a read operation doesn't see the write/delete effect it's not a big deal. It would be better, but it's not required.

The solution should be data-structure-independent, so it shouldn't matter if we write on a vector, list, map or Donald Trump's face.

The data structure could occupy a big amount of memory.

**My solution so far:**

We use two servers: the first server (called `f`) has `Df`, the second server (called `s`) has `Ds` updated.

`f` answers clients requests using `Df` and sends write/delete operations to `s`. Then `s` applies write/delete operations `Ds` sequentially.

At a certain point, all future client requests are redirected to `s`. At the same time, `f` copies `s` updated `Ds` into its `Df`.

Now, `f` and `s` roles are swapped: `s` will answer clients request using `Ds` and `f` will keep an updated version of `Ds`. The swapping process is periodically repeated.

Notice that I omitted on purpose A LOT of details for simplicity (for example, once the swap has been done, `f` has to finish all the pending client requests before applying the write/delete operations received from `s` in the meantime).

Why do we need two servers? Because the data structure is potentially too big to fit into one memory.

**Now, my question is:** there is some similar approach in literature? I came up with this protocol in 10 minutes, I find strange that no (better) solution similar to this one has been already proposed!

PS: I could have forgot some application specs, don't hesitate to ask for any clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme that you have works. I don't see any particular problem with it. This is basically like many databases run their HA solution. They apply a log of writes to replicas. This model affords a great deal of flexibility in how the replicas are formed, accessed and maintained. Failovers are easy, too.

An alternative technique is to use *persistent datastructures*. Each write returns you a new and independent version of the data. All versions can be read in a stable and lock-free way. Versions can be kept or discarded at will. Versions share as much of the underlying state as possible.

Usually, trees underlie such persistent datastructures because it is easy to update a small part of the tree and reuse most of the old tree.

A reason you might not have found a more sophisticated approach is that your problem is extremely general: You want this to work with any data structure at all and the data can be big.

SQL Server Hekaton uses a quite sophisticated data structure to achieve lock-free, readable, point in time snapshots of any database contents. Maybe it's worth a look how they are doing it (they released a paper describing every detail of the system). They also allow for ACID transactions, serializability and concurrent writes. All lock-free.

> At the same time, f copies s updated Ds into its Df.

This copy will take a long time because the data is big. It will block readers. A better approach is to apply the log of writes to the writable copy before accepting new writes there. That way reads can be accepted continuously.

The switchover also is a short period where reads might have a slightly higher latency than normal.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer :) About the copy problem you are right, but I already thought a different solution: `f` copies `Ds` on the disk *before* the swapping. As soon the swap happens, `f` load from disk `Ds` into `Df`. Until this process isn't completed `f` cannot perform any write/delete operation, but this is not a problem: these operation are buffered and applied sequentially as soon the copy process is finished.

Comment: Yes, suspending writes leaves one recent and readable replica. That works.

Comment: I wonder for how long you are willing to suspend writes. If the data is so big that you need two servers you'll have to copy a lot of data over a slow network. 100GB at 100MB/s is 20min suspension. Sounds catastrophic.